# Octopus merge: keep the first parent to the target branch

Tags: git, git-merge

If I run `git merge other-branch`, Git creates a merge commit that has as first-parent the current branch, and as second-parent `other-branch`.

However, if I run `git merge branch2 branch3`, Git creates a merge commit that has as first-parent `branch2` and second-parent `branch3`. How do I force it to keep the first-parent relationship on the current branch?

Comment: I don't think what you've written is true. `branch2` should be the second parent and `branch3` should be the third parent.

Comment: Check your merge commit (with `git cat-file -p HEAD`) just after your octopus merge. Like @mkrieger1 said, parents are indeed 1) the commit your current branch was pointing at before the merge, 2) your `branch2` and 3) your `branch3`

Comment: I have just checked with `git cat-file -p the-commit-id` and I can assure you that the four commits listed as parents are the first commits I specified in the command line. If it worked as you said, the first parent should be the previous commit in the branch, and there should be 5 parents, since I merged 4 branches into the current one.

Comment: "*... since I merged 4 branches into the current one*" Where is *this* stated in the question? You wrote `git merge branch2 branch3`, that's two.